# Controller action for link shortening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

This is what my `Link` model looks like.

```
id: 6,
long_url: "http://google.com",
short_url: "91befc",
created_at: Sun, 22 Nov 2015 11:53:01 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Sun, 22 Nov 2015 11:53:01 UTC +00:00>
```

The `short_url` is being generated using SecureRandom, in an effort to create a bit.ly-like process.

When someone copies and pastes http://bitlyclone.com/3jdjh, which is what is being displayed when they "shorten" their link, I would like it to look up the `long_url` in the database and redirect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about it like this:

```
# app/controllers/links_controller.rb
def show
  link = Link.find_by!(short_url: params[:slug])

  redirect_to link.long_url
end
```

This assumes that you make sure that `long_url` is valid when it is added. Also, using `find_by!` ensures a 404 is rendered if the `short_url` entered doesn't exist.

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/:slug', to: 'links#show'
```

Your routes would then simply direct to this controller action, and pass it the `short_url` as a parameter.

A word of warning, however. This route will match a lot of things, and since routes are matched from top to bottom (in your `routes.rb` file) ensure it doesn't take presedence over other routes in your application.

Comment: This will probably work, but beware of routing issues when there are more routes defined. For example `/admin` will also match this route. This slug route should probably be defined at the bottom of the routes file.

Comment: That's a good point @zwippie. I'm not completely sure, but it might match the root path as well.